# Errors running builder 'Java Builder '

Tags: java, eclipse

Has anyone run into this issue and if so how do you fix it? This has been plaguing me for a while now.

Here is the full error:

[image]

I don't understand the problem. Please help me.

> I found an issue thanks @alfasin!!!:
>        I re-installed eclipse in a new folder and import my projects in this new Eclipse and everything is allright :)

Comment: Do you get the error in eclipse ?

Comment: would be nice to see what code causes this problem

Comment: Yes i got the error from eclipse
@Lucas i don't know which part of my code causes this problem, its very strange...

Comment: Seems like your Eclipse env is messed up. Copy the source (only!) to a fresh folder and "create a new project from existing source".

Comment: @alfasin i get the same error with each project!! Don't tell me i have to uninstall eclipse :(

Comment: @lisa if that's the case then I'm afraid you'll have to re-install eclipse. Do not override the existing installation: install it in a new folder!

Comment: @alfasin- how should i re-install it? should i run eclipse in a new workspace or what do you mean?

Comment: @alfasin i re-installed eclipse in a new folder and i have no problem anymore! thanks as lot  :-)

Comment: Re-installing to a new folder does not work.  This happens when creating a new java project out-of-the-box in Eclipse 19.

Answer (score 21):

This kind of problem is very rare but we have the solution,
If you are using gradle or maven then first close your project and delete from eclipse (remember don't delete from disk),
then delete the files and directories from your project:

1. .settings/
2. .project
3. .classpath
4. .gradle/

then reimport the project in eclipse and you are done. you will no longer face the error like "**Errors running builder 'Java Builder '** "

Cheers.............

Comment: Also, make sure you have a compatible java env: https://java2blog.com/no-compiler-provided-environment-perhaps-running-jre-rather-jdk/

Comment: Also, this: https://github.com/projectlombok/lombok/issues/2882

Comment: John's comment saved my day =)

Answer (score 6):

Your .metadata probably got corrupted.

See this blog post for instructions how to clean this up: http://blog.pdark.de/2011/09/02/restoring-a-corrupted-workspace-in-eclipse/

Comment: Thx ... The explanation of the guy is so complicate that it didn't help me. I don't even understand the first step.... :(

Comment: Added a link how to export your preferences.

Comment: where did you add it?

Comment: In my blog post. This is such a comment question that I'm turning my blog post into a recipe how to fix these issues, constantly improving it.

Comment: Nice! I didn't think about it like that... the original reason I abandoned Eclipse (and moved to Netbeans back then) was because it was so slow that I wanted to cut my veins... Last month I decided to write an Android app and I tried Eclipse (Android developer tools) and it actually worked pretty good (and fast). Though I got to say that a few months ago I tried STS and the env got messed up really easily and more than once (like what happened to our friend Lisa here). You'll never find a blog post on "how to clean the messed-up IntelliJ env" :)

Comment: @AaronDigulla Which tools shoul i use for step 3?

Comment: @lisa: Windows: Task manager, Linux: Depends on your Desktop. Try to press Ctrl+Esc or use `ps|grep eclipse` and `kill` from the command line.

Comment: @lisa: Windows Explorer or any other file copy tool.

Comment: @AaronDigulla i made all steps...and i deleted all my projects and import them new.. I don't have any errors anymore, I just wait to see what happens in the future ...Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

In my case this line on *SpringToolSuite4.ini* produced that error when i tried to do *Clean* on my project:

```
-Xbootclasspath/a:lombok.jar
```

Solution for me: i deleted that line.

Answer (score 1):

While creating the java project on field **-use an execution environment** select `javaSE-1.8` then it will run

Answer (score 0):

If it is an Android application then follow these steps;

1. Right click your project
2. Goto "Android tools"
3. Fix Project Properties

Always work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my build error in eclipse juno by restoring my eclipse work space. Reason being, the .metadata was corrupted so whenever i could try to build the project it could sometimes fail.
Therefore you have to backup yr projects in a folder outside the main work space then deleted the whole work space folder.
Restart eclipse and create a new work space and import yr projects into yr new work space.
Everything will work normally after that.

Thanks Umark

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by reverting the .cproject file in my project folder to an older version (which was created when I setup the project for the first time)

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue when I updated my STS4 version while using old lombok jar version.
My problem was solved by updating lombok version to its latest.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it happens because of Lombok, so fix the issue.

Comment: ... how did you fix it? what exactly what the problem with your usage of lombok?

Comment: go to help and see if Lombok was installed or not, and check the version as well.