# I tried creating a new project in eclipse in Ubuntu 20.04 but it gives me this error Errors occurred during the build

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu, java-17

Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Java Builder' on project 'egg'.
For input string: "H" under radix 16:

[image: Eclipse error]

Comment: try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19981634/errors-running-builder-java-builder). it helped me with the same error

Answer (score 2):

It seems that old Eclipse versions have a [bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=564922) where they incorrectly parse java version information. Java 16 is "G", java 17 is "H" and they try to parse this as an hexadecimal character (0-9 A-F) so it fails.

Try launching eclipse with java 8 or, better, updating Eclipse to the last version (i.e. download Eclipse from their website directly).

Comment: thanks for the fix !! Error is still present but now I can run the java project